# Passing dictionary of colours to view MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to retrieve a dictionary of colours on my model from my view. But I am getting an error that the dictionary of colours can't be serialized. In my model I create the list as follows.

```
public Dictionary<int, Color> Colourlist = new Dictionary<int, Color>();
```

I create the list like this in the model

```
public Dictionary<int, Color> CreateColourPalette()
        {
            Colourlist.Add(1, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f2dcdb"));
            Colourlist.Add(2, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e6b8b7"));
            Colourlist.Add(3, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#da9694"));
            Colourlist.Add(4, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C20046"));
            Colourlist.Add(5, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#d8e4bc"));
            Colourlist.Add(6, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#c4d79b"));
            Colourlist.Add(7, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#76933C"));
            Colourlist.Add(8, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#b7dee8"));
            Colourlist.Add(9, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#92cddc"));
            Colourlist.Add(10, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4F81BD"));
            Colourlist.Add(11, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CCCCFF"));
            Colourlist.Add(12, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#b1a0c7"));
            Colourlist.Add(13, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#711471"));
            Colourlist.Add(14, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#eeece1"));
            Colourlist.Add(15, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ddd9c4"));
            Colourlist.Add(16, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#c4bd97"));
            Colourlist.Add(17, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#494529"));
            Colourlist.Add(18, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00AEEF"));

            return Colourlist;
        }
```

In the view I do the following, basically user clicks button and it calls this function which creates a table, it errors on the Json.Encode line, the Colourlist is populated correctly when I view it but it won't serialise, what am I missing?

```
function createTable()
        {

            var num_cols = 0;
            var headings = new Array();
            headings.push("Cost Type");
            var colours = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Colourlist));
            var checkbox = $("input[name=SelectedYears]");
            for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
                if (checkbox[i].checked) {
                    var chkBoxText = checkbox[i].nextSibling;
                    if (chkBoxText != null)
                        headings.push(chkBoxText.nodeValue);
                }
            }

            var num_cols = headings.length;
            var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
            var tbody = '';

            //create heading row
            tbody += '<tr>';
            for (var j = 0; j < headings.length; j++)
            {
                tbody += '<td style="margin-right:10px;">';
                tbody += headings[j].toString();
                tbody += '</td>'
            }

            var costtypes = $("input[name=SelectedCostTypes]")
            tbody += '</tr>\n';

            for( var i=0; i<costtypes.length;i++)
            {
                if (costtypes[i].checked) {
                    var chkCostTypeText = costtypes[i].nextSibling;
                    if (chkCostTypeText != null)
                    {
                        tbody += '<tr>';
                        tbody += '<td>';
                        tbody += chkCostTypeText.nodeValue;
                        tbody += '</td>'
                        tbody += '<td>';
                        tbody += colours[i];
                        tbody += '</td>'
                        tbody += '</tr>\n';
                    }
                }
            }
            var tfooter = '</table>';
            document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
        }
```

This is the error.

```
Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.
```

Comment: [Have a look here, please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749103/html-rawjson-encode-and-internet-explorer-9)

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but you really need to learn some JS. The code that you currently write is somewhat horrible.

Comment: I am new to javascript so yes its probably not the best, however I thought stack overflow was for people who needed help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your dictionary cannot have non-string keys because they won't be understood correctly by javascript. However fix in your case seems to be simple enough - just turn your dictionary into one that uses string representation of numbers as keys:

```
public Dictionary<string, Color> Colourlist = new Dictionary<string, Color>();

public Dictionary<string, Color> CreateColourPalette()
{
    Colourlist.Add("1", System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f2dcdb"));
    ...
```